# SageMath - echelon_form not giving echelon form

Tags: math, matrix, linear-algebra, sage

According to the [document](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/matrices/sage/matrix/matrix2.html#sage.matrix.matrix2.Matrix.echelon_form)(emphasis mine):

> ```
> echelon_form(algorithm='default', cutoff=0, **kwds)
> ```
>
> Return the echelon form of self.
>
> **OUTPUT**:
>
> The *reduced row echelon form* of self, as an immutable matrix.

Here is what I was doing:

```
sage: A = Matrix([[1,0,3,1,2],[-1,3,0,-1,1],[2,1,7,2,5],[4,2,14,0,6]])
sage: A.echelon_form()

[1 0 3 1 2]
[0 1 1 0 1]
[0 0 0 4 4]
[0 0 0 0 0]
```

I don't think the output above is in *reduced* row echelon form. What I expect is something like this:

```
[1 0 3 0 1]
[0 1 1 0 1]
[0 0 0 1 1]
[0 0 0 0 0]
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is this a bug of Sage?

Comment: This really sounds like a question for the sage users mailing list, or possibly the bug tracker.

Comment: @MarkDickinson So you also think this is a bug, right?

Comment: I agree that it's at the very least a documentation bug, yes: this is, at best, a rather unconventional use of *reduced* row echelon form. Given that this is (presumably) a matrix over the ring of rational integers rather than over a field, I can see a case for dropping the requirement that all the pivot elements are 1, but I'd still expect something called "reduced" echelon form to have the property that the pivot element was the only nonzero element in its column.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Anyway, I've asked a [question](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/35819/echelon_form-not-giving-reduced-echelon-form/) on ask.sagemath.org. Let's wait and see what would they say.

Answer (score 6):

Did you read the first part of the documentation you link to?

> Note This row reduction does not use division if the matrix is not over a field (e.g., if the matrix is over the integers). If you want to calculate the echelon form using division, then use rref(), which assumes that the matrix entries are in a field (specifically, the field of fractions of the base ring of the matrix).

This *is* the reduced form, over the *base ring in question*.  Or maybe it isn't if you think reduced means it must be over a field; I'm not an expert in this terminology.  Anyway, hopefully this clarifies your question.